# "Nothing in SQL buffer to run." message on executing a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh, sqlplus

I am running the following shell script which calls a `.SQL` file, that contains a list of `DELETE` statements. On executing `./delete_crr_input_purge.sh`, I get the following message "**Nothing in SQL buffer to run.**". The .SQL file gets executed anyway but what is wrong with my code in the shell script?

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# @(#)Copyright All Rights Reserved.
# @(#) $Id: run_drm_utility.sh $

# Setup common environment
. `dirname $0`/db_env.sh
cd `dirname $0`

    echo "Enter the SHBA Atomic DB User Name:"
    read USERNAME
    echo "Enter the SHBA Atomic DB User Password:"
    read PASS


cnt=`sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF
        WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
        WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
        connect $USERNAME/$PASS@$ORACLE_SID
        SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
@delete_crr_input_purge.sql;
commit;

        EOF`
echo [$cnt]

return $?
```

[image: Nothing in SQL buffer to run.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this error by removing comments and occurrences of "/" from my .SQL file.

Also, I made sure that each of my SQL statements were in one line, one below the other. Also, no commit statement inside the .SQL file.